# how to convert cocos2d versions between each other

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, universal

Basically, I found this great example of this feature that I want for my app.  The problem is, the coding is written in Cocos2d 0.9 and I'm using version 2.0.  My question is, is there any universal way of converting files between the two, or do they not intermingle?

Answer (score 2):

No universal way. Try to compile it, and see if it at least compiles. If it compiles, it may or may not work, depending on what features/bugs were added/removed between 0.9 and 2.0. It totally depends on the feature. There is no ConvertSourceFileFromCocos2d0.9To2.0.exe tool. :)

Comment: actually that should be ConvertSourceFileFromCocos2d0.9To2.0.app … Mac devs here, not Windows. ;)

Comment: Ehh, muscle memory can't help but auto-type ".exe". :)